# Sort by minute doesn't work

Tags: sql, hour, datepart, minute

I'm trying to sort my photos by hour and minute but it will not catch the minutes - it's just keep saying that nothing exists for that hour and minute. If I'm trying to sort only after the hours, it works perfectly. I have tested `WHERE DATEPART(minute, exif_taken) = "'.$_GET['min'].'"` but I'm keep getting the following error message:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1305 FUNCTION gallery.DATEPART does not exist' in ...
```

I'm using WAMP Server with default settings except for some modules activated for both Apache and PHP like mod_rewrite and php_exif. Here's how my SQL query looks like:

```
SELECT *
FROM photos
WHERE HOUR(exif_taken) = "'.$_GET['h'].'"
AND MINUTE(exif_taken) = "'.$_GET['min'].'"
ORDER BY exif_taken DESC
```

`$_GET['h']` is the hour and `$_GET['min']` the minute.

How can I solve my problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some odd way it's working perfectly now with the SQL query I posted in my question O.o

Answer (score 0):

Are you using MySQL? If true, DATEPART() function doesn't exist. You shoul use MINUTE() function..

Here is the complete documentation.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

BTW, for god sake, sanitize your _GET vars before send to the SQL query. You are exposing your system to SQL Injections.

Comment: Yes. I'm using MySQL and I am using just that - `MINUTE()`. But it doesn't work as I wanted it to work. It just keeps saying that the specific minute does not exists in my database but it does! Sanitize my _GET variables? Many thanks :) I haven't think about that before.